# pandas include grouped value in to dict convert

Tags: python, pandas

here is my data

```
data = [
 {'shape': 'circle', 'width': 10, 'height': 8},
 {'shape': 'circle', 'width': 7, 'height': 2},
 {'shape': 'square', 'width': 4, 'height': 6}
]
```

I am using pandas to aggregate min and max height on each group,
my final result should be:

```
[
  {'shape':  'circle', 'min': 2, max: 8},
  {'shape': 'square', 'min': 6, max: 6}
]
```

here is what I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
my_dict = df.groupby('shape').height.agg(['min', 'max']).to_dict('records')
```

but this results a record without the 'shape' column:

```
[
 {'min': 2, 'max': 8}, 
 {'min': 6, 'max': 6}
]
```

how can I include the grouped by column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group is set as index, try to reset it:

```
df.groupby('shape').height.agg(['min', 'max']).reset_index().to_dict('records')
```